# Using brackets/parentheses in EBNF or GNU Bison grammar

Tags: c++, parsing, syntax, grammar, bison

I am defining my own grammar for a parser generator that outputs C/C++ code. I chose Bison for this, but have run into a problemm. I would like to use brackets ("(", ")") within rules, but Bison doesn't accept themFor example, to declare a character I use (the three dots are instead of all other possible ASCII characters):

```
character: "'" ("\0" | "\t" | "\n" | " " | "!" | ... | "}" | "~") "'";
```

As you can see, I use brackets to say that a character must have a quotation mark, any character and then another quotation mark.

I do something similar for an integer:

```
integer: (["-"] digits) | "0";
```

Is there any way of achieving something similar in Bison? Alternatively, is there a parser generator that accepts EBNF, or even just brackets and that outputs c++ code?

Comment: Normally, the lexical analysis should be done in flex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bison does not support EBNF, only BNF, so if you want optional or grouped things, you'll have to write the rule yourself:

```
character: '\'' character_char '\''
character_char: '\0' | '\t' | ...

integer: opt_negate digits | '0'
opt_negate: | '-'
```

Also, note that `"` characters in bison don't denote literals, so won't do what you want (and are generally useless, as you can't refer to them easily in the lexer).  Always use `'` -- single quotes -- for literal.

In addition, anything that can be recognized by a regular expression (like these examples), should probably be recognized in the lexer and returned to the bison parser as a single token -- it's much simpler, clearer, and more efficient.